# F# what makes it a functional language

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming

What makes a language functional ? In what scenario I should go with functional languages to solve the problem. Is there any major app developed using functional language or it is still in research ?

Comment: First of all higher order functions make a language functional.

Answer (score 2):

A bundle of related features are considered to make a language functional but the most prominent is certainly first-class functions, that is, [the ability to pass around functions as arguments](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html), which helps abstraction. A close related concern is [purity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional), which helps writing code that performs well independently from the current state of values in memory.

Examples of large projects developed with functional languages include [Xen](http://www.xen.org/) (Ocaml), [Ericsson's infrastructure](http://www.ericsson.com/article/open_source_1714451213_c#) (Erlang), and [Twitter](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/twitter_on_scala.html) (Scala - though I'm cheating a little bit here, since [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) also fully integrates the object-oriented paradigm).

Comment: Note that OCaml and F# also offer object-oriented programming.